# shifting code of code behind to viewmodel in wpf

Tags: wpf, mvvm, icommand

Here is my code-behind:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (FrameworkElement fe in canvas.Children)
            {
                double top = (double)fe.GetValue(Canvas.TopProperty);
                double left = (double)fe.GetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty);
            }
        }
```

A 'canvas' is the name of my Canvas control in XAML.  The current code provide me with ability to get the location of images inside the canvas. This is implemented in a code-behind. The question is, how we get the location of images in MVVM manner(using the command to start the process)?

Answer (score 0):

> how we get the location of images in MVVM manner(using the command to start the process)?

Commanding is not needed, simply bind each of the needed properties of each of the canvas(es) to the VM. Then when needed extract the target canvas properties needed to acquire the image.

Answer (score 0):

A good solution would be to use XAML behaviors:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas">
 <i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding YourCommand}" 
                                 CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=canvas}"/>
      </i:EventTrigger>
  </i:Interaction.Triggers> 
</Canvas>
```

In this manner you will have access to your `Canvas` in your `ViewModel` and you can execute the code behind inside the command.

Comment: You have `ElementName` set to "canvas" but the `Canvas` does not have a name...is that a typo?

Comment: In the question it says : "A 'canvas' is the name of my Canvas control in XAML". It is the name.

Comment: Fair enough, then name your example canvas the same. Right? Just to be clear. :-)

Comment: Yep you are right :) I've modified the answer. thank you